# Is there any option available to create Service Connection on Azure Devops with only limited repositories access?

Tags: github, azure-devops

"I want to create a service connection using AzureDevOps with which we get access to only one particular repository. But when I Create service connection it will give access to all repositories present in one account"

I already tried creating a personal access token using Github. But GitHub doesn't allow to create public access token with limited repository access.

How can I generate a personal access token with limited repository access ??

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new GitHub service connection, you can choose Personal Access Token like below.
[image]

Then visit https://github.com/settings/tokens to create personal access tokens and you can choose your expected scope.

[image]

In this time, I choose the public_repo scope, create the token, copy the token to Azure DevOps and create the new GitHub connection.
[image]

As you can see, there are five repositories in my GitHub, one is private and four are public.
[image]

Then in the build pipeline source, I just get the four public repositories and don’t get the private repository.
[image]

Comment: but what if I want to give access to only one public or one private repository?

Comment: According to the github scope list, there is not the option to manual choose which repository can be accessed. The scope diplayed in the list is all the restiction types of all github tokens.

Comment: In our project we don't want to give access of all the private repositories so how can we do that ??

Comment: As you can see, after the repo option, there is a simple note, full control of private reposotires. So don't select the repo scope will meet your need.https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY3C3.png

Comment: is there any possibility of setting scope for particular one repository ??

Comment: Accroding to the documentation, it seems like not. you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github. And in github documentation, there is not a option to set the scope for particular one repository. https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line